# Compare two Array and Order them

Tags: php, arrays

I want to compare two arrays and then order one of them based on a Key field.

```
$arr_x[0] = array('name' => 'max', 'score' => '1');
$arr_x[1] = array('name' => 'june', 'score' => '2');
$arr_x[2] = array('name' => 'jacob', 'score' => '1');
$arr_x[3] = array('name' => 'john', 'score' => '4');



$arr_y[0] = array('name' => 'jacob', 'score' => '7');
$arr_y[1] = array('name' => 'john', 'score' => '6');
$arr_y[2] = array('name' => 'june', 'score' => '9');
```

The result after the order I need is...

```
$arr_x[0] = array('name' => 'max', 'score' => '1');
$arr_x[1] = array('name' => 'june', 'score' => '2');
$arr_x[2] = array('name' => 'jacob', 'score' => '1');
$arr_x[3] = array('name' => 'john', 'score' => '4');

$arr_y[0] = array('name' => 'max', 'score' => '');
$arr_y[1] = array('name' => 'june', 'score' => '9');
$arr_y[2] = array('name' => 'jacob', 'score' => '7');
$arr_y[3] = array('name' => 'john', 'score' => '6');
```

I would really appreciate some help, since I am not able to figure out how to do this. This is an example, in the real case there might be 20-50 in each.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, I just want to compare these two based on the key field "name" and then order $arr_y according to the first array($arr_x).

Comment: $arr_x is already sorted the way you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this (less loops) but here is my two cents:

```
$temp = $arr_z = array();

foreach ($arr_x as $k => $item) {
  $temp[$item['name']]['position_x'] = $k;
}

foreach ($arr_y as $k => $item) {
  if (isset($temp[$item['name']])) {
    $temp[$item['name']]['position_y'] = $k;
  }
}

foreach ($temp as $name => $data) {
  if (isset($data['position_y'])) {
    $arr_z[$data['position_x']] = $arr_y[$data['position_y']];
  } else {
    $arr_z[$data['position_x']] = array('name'=>$name,'score'=>'');
  }
}

$arr_y = $arr_z;
unset($arr_z);
```

This code does not account for the fact that the same name may appear more than once, or that there may be a value if `$arr_y` that does not appear in `$arr_x`.

[Demo here](http://codepad.org/7HiXaQWt).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Is there any way I could append the values of $arr_y that don't appear in arr_x....to $arr_y by adding another step?

Comment: Yes, but this messes with the requirement of `order $arr_y according to the first array ($arr_x)`. Where would you want these values to appear in the final array? At the end?

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1 = array();
$a2 = array();
// fill arrays with values / create two dimensional array
$a3 = array(); //this one will hold sorted array

foreach($a1 as $key => $val){
    if(array_key_exists($key,$a2)){
         // compare values for same key here
        $a3[$key] = $a2[$key]; //put the value and same key to final array
    }
    else {
        $a3[$key] = ''; //init key in final array to empty value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr_y = array();

$arr_y[0] = array('name' => 'jacob', 'score' => '7');
$arr_y[1] = array('name' => 'john', 'score' => '6');
$arr_y[2] = array('name' => 'june', 'score' => '9');


$arr_z = array();

foreach($arr_y as $key => $value)
{
    $arr_z[$value['name']] = $value['score'];
}

$arr_x = array();

$arr_x[0] = array('name' => 'max', 'score' => '1');
$arr_x[1] = array('name' => 'june', 'score' => '2');
$arr_x[2] = array('name' => 'jacob', 'score' => '1');
$arr_x[3] = array('name' => 'john', 'score' => '4');

$arr_y_sorted = array();

foreach($arr_x as $key => $value)
{
    $arr_y_sorted[] = array('name' => $value['name'],'score' => isset($arr_z[$value['name']])?$arr_z[$value['name']]:'');    
}


print_r($arr_y_sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do this (less loops) but here is my two cents:

```
$temp = $arr_z = array();

foreach ($arr_x as $k => $item) {
  $temp[$item['name']]['position_x'] = $k;
}

foreach ($arr_y as $k => $item) {
  if (isset($temp[$item['name']])) {
    $temp[$item['name']]['position_y'] = $k;
  }
}

foreach ($temp as $name => $data) {
  if (isset($data['position_y'])) {
    $arr_z[$data['position_x']] = $arr_y[$data['position_y']];
  } else {
    $arr_z[$data['position_x']] = array('name'=>$name,'score'=>'');
  }
}
```

This code does not account for the fact that the same name may appear more than once, or that there may be a value if `$arr_y` that does not appear in `$arr_x`.

[Demo here](http://codepad.org/7HiXaQWt).